# Still cannot include library to package from another package

Tags: catkin, include, ros-kinetic, find-package, library

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I want to use several libraries created in one package, let say package `A`, into package `B`. Both packages' bareboned CMakeLists look like this:

`A` : The package in which my custom libraries reside:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(A)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES killer_utils_lib
             haha_lib
  CATKIN_DEPENDS ... <-- just a simplification
  DEPENDS ...
}

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(killer_utils_lib src/killer_utils.cpp )
add_library(haha_lib src/haha.cpp)

target_link_libraries(killer_utils_lib 
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
target_link_libraries(haha_lib
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

install(TARGETS
  killer_utils_lib
  haha_lib
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
  PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
)

install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
  PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
)
```

`B` : The package to which I want to import my custom libraries

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(B)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  ...
  killer_utils_lib
  haha_lib
)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  ...
)

include_directories(include)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${killer_utils_lib_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${haha_lib_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(example src/example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example ${catkin_LIBRARIES} killer_utils_lib haha_lib)
```

**package.xml** in `B`

```
<build_depend>killer_utils_lib</build_depend>
<build_depend>haha_lib</build_depend>
```

If I put these two files to compile, The following error messages will pop up:

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "killers_utils_lib"
  with any of the following names:

    killer_utils_libConfig.cmake
    killer_utils_lib-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "killer_utils_lib" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "killer_utils_lib_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "killer_utils_lib" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  task/decision_tasks/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Could not find the required component 'killer_utils_lib'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "killer_utils_lib"
  with any of the following names:

    killer_utils_libConfig.cmake
    killer_utils_lib-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "killer_utils_lib" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "killer_utils_lib_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "killer_utils_lib" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

My question is, I've followed the steps as given in [this ROS Answer article](http://answers.ros.org/question/201977/include-header-file-from-another-package-indigo/), why do my custom shared libraries `killer_utils_lib` and `haha_lib` still not be seen by other packages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281380/still-cannot-include-library-to-package-from-another-package/) by [Megacephalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23714/megacephalo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2018-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Because the cmake config gets generated for the package and not for each lib seperately.

So you need to `find_package` your package `A`. The environment variables (e.g. `A_LIBRARIES`) are then populated with the libraries inside the package.

To cite the question you link to:

> • have a build_depend on my_package in
> its package.xml
>
> • have called
> find_package(my_package REQUIRED) in
> its CMakeLists.txt

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Megacephalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23714/megacephalo/) on 2018-02-01**:
Thank you @mig!! Now I understand better how this building mechanism works!! Now the libraries can be imported into another package!